# How to avoid freeing disk space on a Windows-10 PC

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

I'm working on an application, which can take a backup. In case there is not enough disk space, this application seems not to give an error message.

In order to test this, I'm filling up my PC copying and pasting large files, in order to stuff up my PC.

Once I have less than 5Mb, I run the backup but I don't see any error message.

This is not due to my application, but due to some Windows process: it seems that the amount of free space has been increased up to ±200Mb.

I believe there's some Windows process, which frees disk space in case of a full disk, but this is just the opposite of what I want.

Does anybody know which setting or process is responsible for this and how I can stop Windows from freeing disk space on my computer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What backup? What free space? What's running when you run your test? For example quite a few applications might be watching as well and e.g. clear their temporary files.

Comment: Windows Disk CleanUp is started as a Windows Sheduler Task. Open Sheduler and stop all tasks relative to Disk CleanUp. You may disable those tasks at all, but I'd not recommend this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile I've found the solution:
In the configuration of my PC, there's a chapter `Storage`, which contains the feature `Storage Sense`.

Setting this `Storage Sense` feature `Off` solves my issue.

Comment: I saw your question, and was going to answer with this! :)